# single quote replace by &#39 sql server php

Tags: php, sql-server, special-characters

I have a simple form to add job title in an sql db using php. When I'm adding title  with single quote in the db it this replace by `&#39`;

The column in the db is a nchar(250).

Here's my code:

```
    <?php
include('SQLFunction.php');
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>ITGen Title Creator</title>
    <meta http-equiv=content-type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/symbol.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar sticky-top menu border">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Home</a>
  </nav>
    <img class="imageLogo" src="img/coveo-logo.png"/>
    <h1 class="center">Create a new title</h1>
    <br/><br/>
    <form action="addTitle.php" method="POST" class="myForm">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label center">Title: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6 center">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Title" value="* | *" maxlength='250' required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 center">
                <button type="submit" name="addButton" class="btn btn-add">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <br>
    <hr align="center" size="5" width="90%" noshade>
    <br>

    <h1 class="center">All title</h1>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT *
    from dbo.TITRE
    order by name asc";

    //echo '<br>Sql :' .$sql.'<br>We will comment this out after testing<br>';

    $link = connectMSDB2();

    $getResult = $link->prepare($sql);
    $getResult->execute();
    $result = $getResult->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

    echo "<div >";
    echo "<table class=\"table table-hover tableTest\" style='width:85%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Action</th>";
    echo "<th>ID</th>";
    echo "<th>Title</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"#edit$id\" data-toggle=\"modal\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-update\" data-toggle=\"modal\">Update</button></a>
                  <a href=\"#delete$id\" data-toggle=\"modal\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-delete\" data-toggle=\"modal\">Delete</button></a></td>";
        echo "<td>{$id}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['name']}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<div class=\"modal fade\" id=\"edit$id\" tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"dialog\" aria-labelledby=\"exampleModalLabel\"
     aria-hidden=\"true\">
    <div class=\"modal-dialog modal-lg\" role=\"document\">
        <div class=\"modal-content\">
            <div class=\"modal-header\">
                <h5 class=\"modal-title\">Update title {$row['id']}</h5>
                <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-label=\"Close\">
                    <span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class=\"modal-body\">
                <form action=\"UpdateTitle.php\" method=\"POST\">
                    <div class=\"form-group row\">
                        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"update_id\" value='{$row['id']}'>
                        <label class=\"col-sm-2 col-form-label\">Title: </label>
                        <div class=\"col-sm-10\">
                            <input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" value='{$row['name']}' name=\"Title\" maxlength='250' required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class=\"modal-footer\">
                <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-delete\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">Close</button>
                <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-update\">Update title</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"modal fade\" id=\"delete$id\" role=\"dialog\">
            <div class=\"modal-dialog\">
                <form action=\"deleteTitle.php\" method=\"POST\">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class=\"modal-content\">

                        <div class=\"modal-header\">
                            <h5 class=\"modal-title\">Delete task {$row['id']}</h5>
                            <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-label=\"Close\">
                                <span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class=\"modal-body\">
                            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"delete_id\" value='{$row['id']}'/>
                            <p>
                                Are you sure you want to delete: <br>
                                {$row['name']}
                            </div>
                            <div class=\"modal-footer\">
                                <button type=\"submit\" name=\"delete\" class=\"btn btn-delete\">Delete</button>
                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">NO</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";

    $link = null;
    ?>
    <footer class="page-footer font-small blue">

        <div class="footer-copyright text-right py-3">
            powered by: <img style="width:15%" src="img/machine_learning_icon.png">
        </div>

    </footer>
</div>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here's the code to add the title in the db:

```
    <?php
require_once('SQLFunction.php');

$title = filter_var($_POST['Title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

try {
    $link = connectMSDB2();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.TITRE(name)
              VALUES (:title)";

    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        $message = 'New Title added';
    } else {
        echo "<br>Error :" . $sql . "<br>" . $link->errorInfo();
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $message = 'Unable to process request';
    var_dump($e);
}

$link = null;
header("Location: indexTitle.php");
?>
```

What can I do to arrange this?

I've try the htmlspecialchars_decode but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You specifically told it to do that.

```
$title = filter_var($_POST['Title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

`FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` will encode quotes by default.

You're binding the title value to a prepared statement, so you shouldn't need to filter it at all as far as the query is concerned.

You can store the value as submitted, but you should escape it with `htmlspecialchars` when you output it. If you want to prevent users from using HTML in titles, you can validate their input and if it contains unacceptable characters then show them an error without inserting anything.

Comment: yes, 
     FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING does FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_BACKTICK

Answer (score -1):

Try htmlentities() this will convert single quote to the html entity and while outputting back use html_entity_decode() http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php